Calculating the Probability that Exactly r People Remain in One Queue While Another Queue is Served
I’m working on a queueing theory problem and could use some help.
Imagine two queues, each with n people, where the service time for each person is 3 minutes in average. I’m trying to figure out the probability that, by the time the last customer in the faster queue is served, there are still r customers left in the slower queue.
Also, I’m curious about how r changes as n becomes very large.
Here’s my thought process so far: I considered modeling this as a one-dimensional random walk, where you get +1 if a person in the fast queue is served and -1 if a person in the slow queue is served. But I’m stuck on how to calculate the probability that the random walker ends at $x=2n-r$ and $y=r$.
I came up with this formula using the binomial distribution: $$P = \binom{2n - r - 1}{n - 1} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{2n - r - 1} $$ However, I’m not sure how to factor in the detail that each customer is served every 3 minutes. Is this relevant to the calculation?
Alternatively, should I consider the sum of Poisson random variables, where the service times are also random variables? Given that the service times are exponentially distributed with an average of 3 minutes, we can use the Poisson process.
The number of customers served in time $T$ in each queue can be modeled as a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda T$, where $\lambda = \frac{1}{3}$ per minute.
The probability that exactly $r$ customers remain in the slower queue when the faster queue is empty can be expressed as: $$P(N_f = n \text{ and } N_s = n - r) = \frac{(\lambda T)^{2n - r} e^{-2\lambda T}}{n! (n - r)!}$$
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

You are going to need to know or assume the distribution for service times.  If it is is exactly $3$ minutes in each with no variation, then the answer is debatable between $0$ and $1$.  Perhaps you think the distribution is memoryless and continuous (i.e. exponential).

@Henry  I believe I must assume it’s exponential since the average time is given as 3 minutes. Alternatively, since both of them have the same average time, I can assume they have the same probability. However, I haven’t been able to come up with anything else

OK, so if you think it is memoryless, then the difference $r$ occurs when, in the first $2n−r−1$ services, the winner sees $n−1$ services and the loser $n−r$ services, followed by the winner seeing its nth service leaving an empty queue and a queue of length $r$. You can calculate the probability of this with suitable use of the binomial distribution. As a check, add these up for the gaps being from $r=1$ to $r=n$ and you should get $1$; if you get $\frac12$ then you have probably forgotten that either side can be the winner.

Thanks for your suggestion! So, you think it should be done like this?
The probability of this event can be calculated using the binomial distribution:
[ P = \binom{2n - r - 1}{n - 1} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{2n - r - 1} ]
Where do I incorporate the fact that each customer is served every 3 minutes? Is this detail relevant to the calculation?
Additionally, would another approach be to consider the sum of Poisson random variables, where the service times are also random variables?
Thanks again for your help! @Henry

If you assume that service times have a continuous memoryless distribution (i.e. exponential) at identical rates in the two queues (the precise rate - here $\frac13$ of a customer per minute - does not matter), then you can model this using the binomial distribution as the next service is in either of the queues with probability $\frac12$ independent of the two queues when neither is empty.
The difference $R=r$ occurs when, in the first $2n−r−1$ services the winner sees $n−1$ services and the loser $n−r$ services, followed by the winner seeing its $n$th service leaving an empty queue and a queue of length $r$. Either queue can be empty first, so you get $$\mathbb P(R=r)=2\times \frac{2n-r-1 \choose n-1}{2^{2n-r-1}} \times \frac12= \frac{2n-r-1 \choose n-1}{2^{2n-r-1}}$$ for $r \in {1,2,\ldots,n}$.  You should check this sums to $1$; if you get $\frac12$ then you have probably forgotten that either side can be the winner.
With some effort, you can show for $n>1$ $$\mathbb E[R] = \frac{(2n-1){2n-3 \choose n-1}}{2^{2n-3}}$$ while for $n=1$ you have $\mathbb E[R]=1$. For example for $n=2$ you have $\mathbb E[R]=\frac32$, while for $n=3$ you have $\mathbb E[R]=\frac{15}{8}$, which you can easily check is sensible. As $n \to \infty$ you can show $\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\mathbb E[R] \to \frac2{\sqrt{\pi}}$, associated with $\frac1{\sqrt{2n}}R$ converging in distribution to a standard half-normal distribution.
